# Moving a directory under git repo into a separate repo

Tags: git, repository

I have a git repo and I now want to move one of the subdirectory (with the complete history) into a separate repo.

I know that it is not the proper usecase for git, but is it possible to so in git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using `git subtree`.

Now built-in in msysgit v1.8.0.

Included in git since v1.7.11.